# Laravel download file not working - Argument 3 passed to Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::download() must be of the type

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the user to download a file.

The error message I'm getting:

> Argument 3 passed to Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::download() must be of the type array, null given, called in

My code:

```
 $file = Uploads::where(['username' => $username, 'id' => $id])->firstOrFail();

    return response()->download($file->path, $file->name, header('Content-Type', $file->mime));
```

I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that because you are not passing an array as the third argument. `header()` is a PHP function for sending a raw HTTP header, it does not return anything.

If you want to use that 3rd argument for `download` you would need to pass it an array, but you should try to see if `download` method can set the correct headers for you without passing the 3rd argument and if not then pass your own headers.

Comment: to be precise, to append a header based on the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#file-downloads), should be done through `return response()->download($file->path, $file->name, ['Content-Type' => $file->mime]);`